# Playwright : can’t load session storage from a json file into browser context

Tags: typescript, nestjs, playwright

I want to test my application that is a React / NestJS application.
The session token is located in the sessionStorage in my browser.

So I’m following this part of playwright documentation : https://playwright.dev/docs/auth#session-storage

I managed to save the json file correctly but I don’t manage to load it during the tests.
I don’t understand where you put this code snippet that is displayed in the documentation :

```js
// Set session storage in a new context
const sessionStorage = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('playwright/.auth/session.json', 'utf-8'));
await context.addInitScript(storage => {
  if (window.location.hostname === 'example.com') {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(storage)) {
      window.sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
    }
  }
}, sessionStorage);
```

I tried in beforeEach but with no effect. In which way i should use it please?

I tried with the storageSate way but it does not save the sessionStorage, only the cookies.

auth.setup.ts

```js
import { test as setup } from "@playwright/test";
import path from "path";
import fs from "fs";
require("dotenv").config();

const authFile = path.join(__dirname, "auth.json");

setup("authenticate", async ({ page }) => {
  // Perform authentication steps. Replace these actions with your own.
  await page.goto(process.env.ROOT_URL + "/login");
  await page.locator("input[placeholder=Email]").fill(process.env.LOGIN);
  await page
    .locator("input[placeholder='Mot de passe']")
    .fill(process.env.PASSWORD);
  
  await page.click("button[type=button]");
  // Wait until the page receives the cookies.
  //
  // Sometimes login flow sets cookies in the process of several redirects.
  // Wait for the final URL to ensure that the cookies are actually set.
  await page.waitForURL(process.env.ROOT_URL + "/selectCompanies");

  //await page.context().storageState({ path: authFile });
  const sessionStorage = await page.evaluate(() =>
    JSON.stringify(sessionStorage)
  );
  fs.writeFileSync(authFile, JSON.stringify(sessionStorage), "utf-8");
});
```

configuration :

```js
export default defineConfig({
  testDir: "./tests",
  /* Run tests in files in parallel */
  fullyParallel: true,
  /* Fail the build on CI if you accidentally left test.only in the source code. */
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
  /* Retry on CI only */
  retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,
  /* Opt out of parallel tests on CI. */
  workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,
  /* Reporter to use. See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters */
  reporter: "html",
  /* Shared settings for all the projects below. See https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions. */
  use: {
    /* Collect trace when retrying the failed test. See https://playwright.dev/docs/trace-viewer */
    //trace: 'on-first-retry',
    // Capture screenshot after each test failure.
    screenshot: "only-on-failure",
    headless: false,
  },

  /* Configure projects for major browsers */
  projects: [
    // Setup project
    {
      name: "setup",
      testMatch: /.*\.setup\.ts/,
      testDir: "setup",
    },
    {
      name: "chromium",
      use: {
        ...devices["Desktop Chrome"],
      },
      dependencies: ["setup"],
    },
  ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you should add storageState option in your 'chromium' project in use section of configuration file:

```
/* Configure projects for major browsers */
projects: [
// Setup project
 {
   name: "setup",
   testMatch: /.*\.setup\.ts/,
   testDir: "setup",
 },
 {
   name: "chromium",
   use: {
     ...devices["Desktop Chrome"],
     storageState: `playwright/.auth/session.json`,
   },
   dependencies: ["setup"],
 },
],
```